# How do i combine 2 lines in a text file in python?

Tags: python

I need help combining 2 lines together in a text file, so for example:
My text file looks something like this:

Line 1

Line 2

Line 3

I want to combine Line 2 into line 1 then print the content of the text file so it looks something like this:

Line 1 
Line 2

Line 3

I know how to print the content of the file using:
Print file.read()

I just don’t understand how to combine the first 2 lines.

Comment: Questions should normally include some of the example code you are working with.  Use 4 spaces to make the code appear as code.  On to your question, you have "new line characters" that are making line 2 appear on the next line.  In unix, this is usually "\n" and in windows it can be "\r\n".  By printing with "repr" this will display the hidden characters.  `print(repr(file.read()))`  Edit your answer with the output from that and you're likely to get a better response.

Comment: Attempt to solve the problem first and post your results. SO users will be more willing to help you with your question if you show that you have at least taken a stab at the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The other posts fail to show you how to combine only the first and second lines before printing the rest of the file. You may or may not desire a space inbetween the lines as I have done. Here is an example:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    line1 = f.readline().strip()
    line2 = f.readline().strip()
    print line1 + " " + line2
    for other_line in f:
        print other_line.strip()
```

Comment: Calling `f.readlines()` isn't necessary since you can just iterate directly over `f`.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thank you! I'll update my response.

Answer (score 0):

You file is stored with strings having '\n' in-between every sentence.

To combine lines,
Open your file. Read the contents and split the lines to form a list of strings. Now join them with ' '(space).

```
with open('sample.txt') as f:
    print(" ".join(f.read().splitlines()))
```

For combining every two lines,

```
>>> with open('sample_log.txt') as f:
...     content = f.read().splitlines()                                         ... 
>>> 
>>> print "\n".join(" ".join(two_lines) for two_lines in zip(content[::2],content[1::2]))+(content[-1] if len(content)%2!=0 else '')
```

Here, for example, if

```
>>> content = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']                                     >>> zip(content[::2],content[1::2])
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f')]
>>> [' '.join(twos) for twos in zip(content[::2],content[1::2])]
['a b', 'c d', 'e f']
>>> "\n".join(' '.join(twos) for twos in zip(content[::2],content[1::2]))
'a b\nc d\ne f'
>>> print "\n".join(' '.join(twos) for twos in zip(content[::2],content[1::2]))
a b
c d
e f
>>> print "\n".join(' '.join(twos) for twos in zip(content[::2],content[1::2])) + ("\n"+content[-1] if len(content)%2!=0 else '')
a b
c d
e f
g
>>>
```

If you want to combine only the first two lines then,

```
number_of_lines_to_combines=2
content=[]
with open('sample_log.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if number_of_lines_to_combines>0:
            number_of_lines_to_combines-=1
            content.append(line.rstrip()) #rstrip is used to get rid of new line
        else:
            content.append(line) # append with new line
print "".join(l)
```

Comment: This joins every line together, not just the first 2. Also, you could've just called `file.readlines`

Comment: There is difference between readlines() and read()! Readlines holds the trailing newline character too!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
l1, l2, l3 = [i.strip('\n') for i in open('filename.txt')]
new_lines = ["{} {}".format(l1, l2), l3]
print('\n'.join(new_lines))
```

Comment: This would work, provided there are only three lines in the input file.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
with open('lines.txt') as f:
    all_lines = f.readlines()
    all_lines = [x.strip() for x in all_lines if x.strip()]
    two_lines = " ".join(x for x in all_lines[:2])
    lines_left = " ".join(x for x in all_lines[2:])

    print two_lines
    print lines_left
```

Output

```
Line 1 Line 2

Line 3
```

Comment: There's no need to `str`ingify the lines since they're already strings. `' '.join(all_lines[:2])` and `'\n'.join(all_lines[2:])` would work.

Comment: @Wyatt yes I have made the change